# grails params vs custom beans maybe just enhancements for pagination

Tags: grails

Will try to make it quick,  decided to use a bean to handle everything related to a controllers input/output

so in a controller, using a custom bean to handle everything including [offset/max](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuemail-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugin/queuemail/validation/QueueMailBean.groovy) which is really where the question comes in and around I guess `g:paginate` since the issue was with this really.

```
def something(MyBean bean) {

  render 'view', model:[bean:bean]
}
```

I know you can override and in my case since I am modelling bean which includes my content and now overridden here:

```
<g:paginate ... max="${bean.max}"
```

I guess I could have also done:

```
 render 'view', model:[params:bean]
```

which would have overridden params and hence me then not having to declare `max=mycustom.max`. I have seen in the code of paginate that it does a default of params.max or offset if not default.

I guess my bigger question was maybe an enhancement of someway getting grails to guess that current params is actually declared bean method on the top of the controller. That way everything would be just so smoooooth

I think this might have to be raised as a wish list to paginate but kind of touches over how grails works with params

By the way at the moment, I ended up with :

```
 def something(MyBean bean) {
      params.max=bean.max
      params.offset=bean.offset
      //a little ugly I know but hence my question
      render 'view', model:[bean:bean]
    }
```

Btw. typically this works correctly anyways since the user would paginate do a `GET` which posts and hence received as a params anyways so it doesn't happen. I have further complications around relisting which doesn't rely on post and more on a session map which I think created the question.

Comment: Why not just override the `g:paginate` implementation of the tag with your own that first looks for `bean.max` etc?

Comment: Indeed, but I think my question was more around can grails be enhanced to acknowledge current params is what user has defined as a bean that way as I say everything everywhere/every other plugin reliant on params would not suffer from this issue.

Comment: Then the answer would be no. Sorry :/

Comment: You don't get if you don't ask. So had to be tried :) Maybe one of the geniuses like Burt will click a finger and go ah ye no problems,  it is in the next release